# Can time of possession for the two teams of an NFL game add up to less than 60 minutes?

Tags: statistics, nfl

In a December 13, 2015 game between the Atlanta Falcons and Carolina Panthers, the time of possession of the two teams was recorded as:

Falcons: 28:21

Panthers: 31:21

Adding these two gives a total game time of 59:42, which is 18 seconds short of a full game. Is there an explanation for this? Or is this simply an error in the source data?

EDIT

Another game I found that has a similar discrepancy:

http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2004101711/2004/REG6/broncos@raiders#tab=analyze&analyze=boxscore

That is from NFL.com. It's one second short of a full game. Another error in the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't added the source of data which may help in clarifying but official NFL website shows the possession of these two teams for this match as:

Falcons: 28:30
Panthers: 31:30
Total: 60

[image: nfl stat]

[Source](http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2015121307/2015/REG14/falcons@panthers#menu=gameinfo%7CcontentId%3A0ap3000000603267&tab=analyze)

ESPN also shows the same stat.

[image: espn stat]

[Source](http://www.espn.in/nfl/game?gameId=400791604)

So, 59:42 might be an error.

Comment: I had seen that ESPN page, while looking for an alternate data source, but I must have overlooked the Possession graphic. Thanks!